How to Create a Multi-Select Dropdown in Dynamics 365 FO for Enum Values?
I'm trying to implement a multi-select dropdown in Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations that allows users to select multiple values from an enum. Specifically, I have an enum with options like "Depreciation," "Acquisition Adjustment," and "Acquisition." I want the user to be able to select more than one of these values, similar to a standard dropdown, but with the option to select multiple items (see attached image for a single-select example).

Since standard dropdowns in D365 FO only allow single selection, I’ve tried a few workarounds, but haven't had much luck. Here are the solutions I attempted:
Dialog with Checkboxes: I created a dialog with checkboxes for each option. This allows users to select multiple options, but it doesn't integrate smoothly with forms where a typical dropdown might be used. Here’s the code I used:
Custom List Control with Multi-Select Capability: I considered creating a custom form with a list control where users can check multiple items. However, this approach feels cumbersome for a basic multi-select dropdown experience.
Using a Reference Table: Another approach was to create a related table for "Fixed Asset Type Selections" and use a subgrid to allow adding multiple records (each representing a selected type). This solution is better for persisting values but feels overly complex for my needs.
Question: can anyone suggest an approach that provides a smoother user experience? I’d like something that either replicates the look and feel of a dropdown or integrates more naturally into forms. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Look into SysLookupMultiSelectCtrl, e.g. here https://axvigneshvaran.wordpress.com/2023/08/06/creation-of-multiselection-lookup-in-the-dialog-using-x-in-d365-for-finance-operations/

@FH-Inway I suggest this question should be reopened and the info from this article added as an answer rather than as a comment
